# Is it possible to get all streets in a country from the map?

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, openstreetmap, yandex-maps

Seems like `GoogleMap` doesn't provide any `API` for gettings all streets from country (just from rectangular bounding box).

Maybe is possible to grab whole database with streets from the map, but I don't know how. Any map is appropriate.

Any advices?

Comment: Similar to [Getting all streets visible in Google map's viewport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495563/getting-all-streets-visible-in-google-maps-viewport)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not only is not possible in the Google Maps API - extracting data like that is explicitly forbidden by the [Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=en).

See: 10.1.3 Restrictions against Data Export or Copying. 
Especially (c) No Mass Downloads or Bulk Feeds of Content.

You could however try something like [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) for example.

It allows you to [export data](http://www.openstreetmap.org/export) for free although there are download limits in place.

Comment: yeah, I read this. Maybe OpenStreetMap (because it's open :)) provides such API, but I haven't found any example.

Comment: Can't you see the big green export button on the page I linked too? http://www.openstreetmap.org/export#map=5/51.495/7.603

Comment: If you want to grab a whole city worth of streets, you will almost certainly run into the download limits. The [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) allows you to request only certain kinds of objects (in your case streets).

Comment: @VeaceslavGaidarji If you need a whole country I suggest the exports from [geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/) and handle this via various tools (osmosis) or just write a script which extracts the name for specific key value pairs: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway